# leaflet.js disable duplicated world maps

Tags: leaflet

We need to disable duplicated world maps at the left and right side of the main world map, which is showing by default.
Problem is that we need exact zoom level there and sometimes leaflet showing duplicates...
Is it possible to remove duplicates at all?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You will disable the `noWrap` property of your `TiledLayer` (which extends `GridLayer`). Documentation [here](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#gridlayer-nowrap)

```
var layer = new L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    noWrap: true
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work in 1.0, but I won't downvote, just sharing.

Comment: So I haven't used 1.0 yet, but I still see the documentation on the `noWrap` property here: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#gridlayer-nowrap and it seems as expected. What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: @PatrickD According to this issue all the way at the bottom https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2981 in 1.0+ to use `noWrap` you must also set TileLayer `bounds`

Answer (score 4):

If you use `react-leafet` you can set this prop in `TileLayer` component:

```
<MapContainer
  center={{ lat: 51.505, lng: -0.09 }}
  zoom={5}
  style={mapStyle}
  scrollWheelZoom={true}
>
  <TileLayer
    noWrap={true}
    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
  />
</MapContainer>
```

Comment: it causes strange behavior for some reason, i think its a bug in the library

Comment: In latest version of React-leaflet, there is no need of boolean value, just mention 'noWrap' property in the TileLayer.