# How to get a fixed map when maximum zoom out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

When I zoom out my map, I got this image:

[image: Multiple worlds]

But I want to fixed this map such as when I maximum the zoom out I got this map:

[image: One world]

I am a newbie and I googled many sources but still don't know how to do that. I am really appreciate if someone can help me with this.

P/s: I still cannot include pictures in my post yet so I apologize for the redirection to view my pictures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [leaflet.js disable duplicated world maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638118/leaflet-js-disable-duplicated-world-maps)

Comment: @chazsolo Thank you. I will give it a shot