# how to limit map repeat on leaflet?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, repeat

[image: image that shows problem]

I want only one world map to be shown.

I tried searching about the problem But I did not find a solution.

Comment: Does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638118/leaflet-js-disable-duplicated-world-maps answere your question?

Comment: yes it answered.